# How would you know what to do with the "Ashen Mist Heart"?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I know what it does, but when does the **plot** tell you what it is and where to use it?
Granted you get a vague item description, but is that all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best hint lies in the item description:

> Manifestation of ashen mist received from the ancient dragon.
>   The magic of the ancient dragon allows one to **delve into the memories of the withered.**"

Throughout the game you run into multiple interact-able giant corpses, one of which happens to be the only thing of significance behind a door that requires the King's Ring to access. Without the Ashen Mist Heart interacting with the corpses hints at coming back later (*everything in the game that is interact-able has a purpose, there are no 'flavor' interactions that I know of, only ones that tell you do not have the required key. Either explicitly or implicitly*).

Comment: alas nothing happened..

Comment: Also I recently learned that Nashandra tells the player to "Seek the forest, you, where those wretched Giants slumber." after the Ashen Mist has been obtained. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201091/spoiler-alert-why-does-nashandra-only-appear-when-you-have-the-giants-kinship?lq=1